# How can you store more than one word in a php $_SESSION?

Tags: php, variables, session

Bit of a newbie here and hoped someone could help me?

All i'm trying to do is store more then one word in a $_SESSION. I've done a MySQL query to retrieve a member name from a database and this returns "Mr Brown". I've then stored the $memberName in a session like this:

```
$_SESSION['MemberName'] = $memberName;
```

If I echo straight after, it does give me "Mr Brown".
But if I redirect to another page (header( 'Location: ../memberIndex.php' );) it doesn't get stored! It works ok if the $memberName is one word like "Bob", but as soon as there is a space in it, it doesn't transfer over. Other variables are stored ok as there ID numbers etc, its just this one? Can anyone help please? I've googled for ages and I can't see anything that lets me put two or more words into a $_SESSION variable?!? ...HELP!

```
<?
session_start(); 

$HTTP_POST_VARS["submit"]; 
$Username = $_POST['username']; 
$Password = $_POST['password']; 

$query = "SELECT * FROM MemberLogin WHERE username = '$Username' AND password = '$Password'"; 

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
   extract($row); 
   $_SESSION['MemberID'] = $id;
   $_SESSION['MemberName'] = $memberName;

   //echo $_SESSION['MemberName'];

   header( 'Location: ../memberIndex.php' ) ; 
}
```

Ok, bit of an update. I've just tried another script:

```
<?
session_start();

$_SESSION['MemberName'] = "Matt Brown";

//echo $_SESSION['MemberName'];

header( 'Location: testSession2.php' ) ;

?>
```

And when its transferred to testSession2.php, it works!
So whats the difference? Where have I gone wrong? If I allocate the _SESSION with "Matt Brown", its ok. But if I allocated the _SESSION with $memberName that has "Matt Brown" in it, it doesn't?!? Oh i'm so confused!

Comment: You can store an array in your $_SESSION variable. Have you set session_start(); at the top of your files?

Comment: Yes, sorry, its at the start of every page.

Comment: `"Mr Brown"` - is that a string? That should **work** without any problems. Post an MCVE.

Comment: Ever so sorry Karoly, whats a MCVE? (Newbie, forgive me!) And yeah, its a string.

Comment: Googling the problem, there's lots on $_SESSION and how to store variables in them, but none of the examples mentioned them having more then one word :-(

Comment: Just seen what a MCVE is, two ticks

Comment: @Origination, a variable cand store multiple words as a single string. When you pass that variable to the $_SESSION there is no reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: Post code in the *question*. That doesn't look like an *MCVE*. Will it reproduce the problem if I run it on my machine?

Comment: @lonut, thank you! Can you see anything i've done wrong in the code? Or should it work?

Comment: @Origination, what is in your $memberName? Where do you store something in that?

Comment: @karoly I do hope so! Ha! Hope you'll get the same problem as I have no idea what i've done! Two ticks, will do it now

Comment: It was a rhetorical question. I'm OUT.

Comment: As we don't have a copy of your database, that code won't run on our machines..... an MCVE should be self contained code, with no external dependencies

Comment: Can you post here the "memberIndex.php" code? You can also use http://jsfiddle.net. Tks.

Comment: @ThiagoA.Klein, and how would he use PHP code in http://jsfiddle.net ?...just curious...

Comment: Beg your pardon Mark, I assumed you'd just need to see my shoddy code! Two ticks, i'll tweet it now and update
And thank you Thiago, I haven't tried it on jsfiddle as it works ok on a single page, it stores it fine. Its only when its re-direct onto another. Can jsfiddle do that?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the string coming out of the database might contain strange characters that cause the second word to be invisible on the next page? Maybe try it with other rows, or update the DB to say something else.

Comment: Also, as an aside, *please* don't use mysql_* functions, they are insecure. See http://www.phptherightway.com/#mysql_extension_title for details.

Comment: Sorry @Ionut, it's true, my bad. What about http://phpfiddle.org ?

Comment: @Jez Hi ya Jez, thanks ever so much. I have, yeah, as i've had problems with that in the past when I was learning. But it is literally two words, someones name with just a space. It gets entered into the database with stripslashes which I thought gets rid of any strange characters?!?

Comment: @Jez However, it does seem to be what its pulling from the database. I've just tested another and it seems to work if I set it manually, its just when its two words from the DB

Comment: @Origination Stripslashes just literally removes slashes, it won't do any escaping. The thing you want if you're using mysql_* functions is mysql_real_escape_string, but again that is deprecated. You should look into mysqli or PDO, they may well avoid this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping $memberName in double quotes. Not sure if that will work though.

Also, *please* use PDO instead of the mysql extension-it's much safer: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Comment: Thank you! I do think I still use the 'old way', just don't have time to learn any newer methods unfortunately. I will try PDO as its still not having it!

Comment: PDO is really easy to use and comes with any packaged PHP installation. If you're going to be writing a lot of database-driven code I highly suggest making yourself familiar with it. Also, the base mysql_ methods are removed entirely in PHP 7, and have been deprecated since 5.5 I believe.

Comment: I don't understand why is this accepted as an answer. Can someone please explain?!